# Puppet - Remove ALL versions of Java from PATH

Tags: java, path, puppet

I am attempting to remove ALL version of java from windows PATH via Puppet.
I will replace it with %JAVA_HOME%\bin.

Here is the current code:

```
include windows_path

define obsolete_java {
    windows_path {
       $name:
           ensure => absent,
           directory => "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\$name\\bin";
    }
}

define windows_java::setup (
  $ensure        = 'present',
  $source        = undef,
  $file          = undef,
  $package       = undef ) {

  case $::osfamily {
    Windows  : { $supported = true }
    default : { fail("The ${module_name} module is not supported on ${::osfamily} based systems") }
  }

  # Validate parameters
  if ($source == undef) {
    fail('source parameter must be set')
  }

  if ($file == undef) {
    fail('file parameter must be set')
  }

  if ($package == undef) {
    fail('package parameter must be set')
  }

  # Validate input values for $ensure
  if !($ensure in ['present', 'absent']) {
    fail('ensure must either be present or absent')
  }

  if ($caller_module_name == undef) {
    $mod_name = $module_name
  } else {
    $mod_name = $caller_module_name
  }

  if ($ensure == 'present'){
    # ensures main directory exists
    file {'C:\Program Files\Java':
      ensure => directory,
    }

    # copies source executable over
    file { "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\$source":
      ensure             => present,
      source             => "puppet:///extra_files/java/windows/$source",
      before             => Package["$package"],
      source_permissions => ignore,
    }

    # Name of package must match name when installed
    package { "$package":
      ensure             => installed,
      source             => "C:\\Program Files\\java\\$source",
      install_options    => '/s',
    }

    # sets JAVA_HOME. If already existant, replaces it.
    windows_env { "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\$file":
      mergemode => clobber,
    }

    # removes previous Java from path
    obsolete_java {'jdk1.7.0_51':}

    # Adds JAVA_HOME to the path.
    windows_path {'javaPath':
      ensure      => present,
      directory       => "%JAVA_PATH%\bin",
     }
  } else {

    package { 'remove-package':
      name   => "$package",
      ensure => absent,
    }

    windows_env { 'JAVA_HOME':
      ensure    => 'absent',
      mergemode => clobber,
    }

    windows_path {'remove_java_path':
     ensure    => absent,
     directory => "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\$file\\bin",
    }
  }
}
```

Specifically:

```
define obsolete_java {
    windows_path {
       $name:
           ensure => absent,
           directory => "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\$name\\bin";
    }
}
```

called here:

```
# removes previous Java from path
obsolete_java {'jdk1.7.0_51':}
```

Is it possible just have it remove anything it finds under: C:\Program Files\Java\any_jdk
bin ?

Edit:  More importantly, can I force it to find any directory that contains the word "java" and remove it from PATH?

Comment: Did you check the `recurse` attribute?

Comment: @utrecht the `windows_path` [type](https://github.com/basti1302/puppet-windows-path/blob/master/lib/puppet/type/windows_path.rb) has none.

Comment: Correct it doesnt.  Essentially when java gets installed, I now have it adding `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to Windows `PATH`.  However, if you do not remove previous java directories from PATH, it will find those first and use them over `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as the `windows_path` type is somewhat complex, there seems to be no conceivable way for the [provider](https://github.com/basti1302/puppet-windows-path/blob/master/lib/puppet/provider/windows_path/path_provider.rb) to prefetch the full list of existing paths. You will therefor be unable to `purge` the java paths.

That leaves you with only one option that I can see: Create an [external fact](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/2.1/custom_facts.html#external-facts) (or plain custom fact) to retrieve the list of directories in the `PATH`. If you don't use Facter 2, you will need to get the delimited `PATH` string and process it on the master. Facter 2 can hand an array to the master.

If you have them in a variable, say `$path_list`, you can hand them to a similar defined type as the one you are using already.

```
filter_path { $path_list: }

define filter_path {
    if $name =~ /java/ {
        windows_path { $name: ensure => absent, directory => $name }
    }
}
```

Comment: This may work yes.  I will attempt it.  
On a side note, I wish Puppet would handle wild cards so I could just use your previous code:

`define obsolete_java {
    windows_path {
       $name:
           ensure => absent,
           directory => "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\$name\\bin";
    }
}`

and just change it to :

`directory => "C:\\Program Files\\$name\\*";`

then just call:

`# removes previous Java from path
obsolete_java {['Java','java']:}`

Comment: Well, Puppet in and of itself *can* support this kind of stunt, but you would have to patch the provider to make sense of it.

Comment: That sounds like more hassle than its worth.  Thanks Felix, your help is always appreciated.

Comment: Hmm.  Do you see anyway of doing it with this?  https://forge.puppetlabs.com/badgerious/windows_env

I still dont think its possible.  What I can do for the time being is prepend `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to `PATH` so it will take precedence.   Then work on a custom fact to handle filtering and removal.  At least it would provide a work around.

Comment: `windows_env` - not really. You could use `merge_mode => clobber` and set the PATH to what you consider clean...but expect to *clobber* some custom entries on some machines ;-)

Comment: yea.  clobbering PATH wouldnt be wise :)  Ok.  Moving on.  thanks again!!